# Can a thermal fuse of a higher rated current be used safely?

Tags: protection, fuses, circuit-protection, thermal, component-selection

I want to replace a 115°C 250V 2A thermal fuse used in a fan motor. The only fuses available locally are 115°C 277V 15A. Can I use the higher current rated thermal fuse?

Since it is a thermal fuse, I would expect only the temperature to matter...

Comment: What is this fuse to be used in? Normally thermal fuses are used in devices that get hot as part of normal operation, such as a hair dryer. If the fan stops it will overheat and open the fuse, which is not resettable.

Comment: @Sparky256 Updated question, fuse found in fan motor.

Comment: The purpose of a thermal fuse is to permanently open upon reaching a certain temperature. Assuming that is the purpose of this particular thermal fuse, then the larger current rating should be OK. But you have not shared full data from both fuses so that we can confirm. Also, a larger thermal fuse may take longer to open due to thermal mass. So there could be some small uncertainties there. It is better than nothing. But may not provide exactly equivalent protection. Also, it is worth asking, why did the original fuse open? Are you sure the motor is not faulty?

Comment: @mkeith I do not know why the fuse blew in the first place. A visual inspection of the motor shows nothing out of the ordinary... I'm thinking to replace the fuse and see if it blows again sometime soon... if it does can put more work towards narrowing down cause.

Comment: Seems reasonable. If you haven't already, then you can also just bypass the fuse and run the fan under close observation for a while to see if it overheats. If it does, you may want to correct that problem before blowing another thermal fuse.

Comment: Update: the motor has been running daily now for quite some time using the double fuse in series approach suggested. So far so good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case Barry partially has the correct answer, now that the OP has updated the question.

A motor can overload in many ways, but a stuck rotor (for whatever reason) needs to have a fuse that blows fast based on extreme over current. *So the current rating of the fuse does matter in this case.*

A motor can 'slow cook' due to an overload based on cracked or dry bearings or an over voltage condition. Not enough over current to pop the fuse but over time the motor windings become hot enough to burn the enamel coating and now you risk having a shorted motor. *This is where a thermal fuse can sense a dangerous situation* and open up based on extreme heat-not current.

Normally a motor is on a circuit being fed by a breaker panel, but tripping a breaker is a last resort, as they can only trip OFF so many times before the contacts wear out.

*Be smart and take the time to find the right thermal fuse*. Contact the motors manufacture and search fuse manufactures for something much closer to the original fuse.

What made the original fuse open in the first place? Check the motor out real good or it may have a problem that will blow the next fuse right away.

Comment: Alternatively, OP could perhaps use the 115C thermal fuse and a 2A standard fuse in series.

Comment: Tripping a breaker is to be avoided for other reasons, like shutting down the rest of the circuit and the fact that the breaker's tripping current is likely significantly more than the fan's stall current. Breakers are good for hundreds of trips as long as they're not near the kA rating.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Combining is a neat idea! That way I can get the motor running sooner than later.

Comment: Update: the motor has been running daily now for quite some time using the double fuse in series approach suggested. So far so good...

Comment: The 2A thermal fuse is not meant to act an electrical fuse. It's just not rated for use at over 2A!

Answer (score 1):

The 2A rating on the thermal fuse is the maximum operating current the fuse can take while meeting its other specifications. I.e. if you put more than 2A through it, it's likely to overheat and get damaged, but it's not guaranteed to interrupt current reliably when that happens. It's not meant to function as a current limiter!

A 15A thermal fuse will be just fine for the application. A thermal fuse is a single-use thermostat, more-or-less.

You can always add an electrical overload fuse for peace of mind. But it should be rated for *less* than 2A most likely. I bet you the fan is consuming about 1A or less when it's running. Just measure the normal operating current, multiply by 1.25, and use the next larger slow-blow 5x20mm fuse size.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that your larger thermal fuse may provide inadequate protection, because it will have more thermal mass and thus take more time to heat up, i.e. in a locked rotor condition, and could allow the windings to overheat and burn before the fuse melts.

A higher voltage rating in itself won't cause any safety issues but could also mean the fuse is physically larger, and could slow its response too.

Answer (score -3):

A 2 ampere fuse cannot safely be replaced by a 15 ampere fuse irregardless of the type of fuse. You don't say the type of equipment using this fuse. What do you think would happen if a fault in the equipment caused it to draw, for example, 10 amperes? The specified 2 ampere fuse would blow rather quickly.  The 15 ampere fuse would never blow but your equipment could either be destroyed or worse start a fire. Don't take a chance. Get the correct fuse.

Comment: It is a _thermal_ fuse, which reacts to a too hot environment. The current itself should not heat the fuse, so current rating must be higher than max. expected current. A much higher rating is no problem here.

Comment: @Barry, updated question - fuse used in fan motor